# Freemarker. Как вызвать java-метод в template из переданного java Document в качестве модели?

Tags: java, freemarker

Freemarker. Передаю в качестве модели Java-объект класса и привязываю его к "doc". В шаблоне пытаются вызвать любой метод, даже самый простой .toString(), получаю всегда NonMethodException

fr.opensagres.xdocreport.core.XDocReportException: freemarker.core.NonMethodException: For "...(...)" callee: Expected a method, but this has evaluated to a sequence+hash (wrapper: f.e.dom.NodeListModel):
==> doc.toString

Пример вызова из шаблона:

```
${doc.toString()}
```

Как вызвать java-метод в template из переданного java-объекта в качестве модели?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class DocumentTools{
 public static String method(Document doc, ...){
 // вызываем метод doc
}
}
```

передаём в качестве параметров в отчёт
doc - объект Document,
docTools - объект DocumentTools

в шаблоне

```
${docTools.method(doc, ...)}
```